# WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, amazon-eks, deis

I configured deis workflow in aws eks cluster. after that created deis apps and deployed in deis local repository by,

`git push test test:master`

when deploying, docker file is executed. here is my docker file

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12
#FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG SOURCE_VERSION=na
ENV SOURCE_VERSION=$SOURCE_VERSION

RUN apk add --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9  --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
#apt-get update &&\
#apt-get install -y make gcc wget
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .

RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3200

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

this results error like,

```
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main: temporary error (try again later)

WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main: No such file or directory

ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community: temporary error (try again later)

WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community: No such file or directory
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  bash (no such package):
    required by: world[bash]

The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*' returned a non-zero code: 1

remote: 2021-11-15 13:30:22.569253 I | Error running git receive hook [Build pod exited with code 1, stopping build]

To ssh://deis-builder.app-test.paceup.io:2222/pu-api-gateway.git
 ! [remote rejected] test -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@deis-builder.app-test.paceup.io:2222/pu-api-gateway.git'
```

I am totally new to docker, deis and eks. if anyone can help it would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer is that we have configured nodegroup setup in amazon linux which didn't support this deployment. we changed the nodegroup for eks optimized ubuntu and deployed the app using docker and working fine.

Edit:
This is working in some of the Linux versions. In my case it's working on EKS version 1.9 but not working in EKS version 2.0 and above.

This error may come due to DNS issue also while building the docker image pus the dns flag and mention google dn 8.8.8.8. Or edit the resolv.conf and add the nameserver 8.8.8.8 in the container

I hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my machine had many symptoms of a network configuration problem:

- A Dockerfile that had to download zip files from the net could not do this anymore and threw the warning in question which stopped the build. I could download the zip files when entering the URL:s in the browser instead, it was a problem of the container. I checked the same Dockerfile on another healthy machine and the build ran through.
- I had lost the connection to the internal dns server. I could not ping another machine by its name anymore, but had to use its internal IP, although the day before, the ping had worked.
- I could see any GCP project items only in Firefox incognito mode.

Answer insofar is: change the machine and test whether it does not work only on your machine. If that is true, the workaround is already done. As the next step, try to fix any other network problems, and it is likely that this will get rid of the warning.

UPDATE: The problem was a running container that gave my machine its own network. When I ran `docker-compose down`, the network worked again. When I removed the network from the docker-compose file, the download from inside the container worked again, the warning in question was gone.